# Getting Prefabs gameobjects with tags from folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-container

I have some problems. When I refreshed codes or tags on projects. This code does not work. When I rechoose tags again on prefabs, it starts to work again.

This piece of code is not working and I'm not sure why:

`"Map[list.Count()] = GetComponent<GameObject>();"`

I'm using this code because when I created new map,everytime I don't want to add it.

```
void Start()
{
    var list = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject)).Cast<GameObject>().Where(g => g.tag == "Map").ToList();
    var i = 0;
    Debug.Log(list.ToList());
    Map[list.Count()] = GetComponent<GameObject>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
            Debug.Log(item);
            Map[i] = item;
            i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you click "Apply" on prefabs to save the changes

Comment: Yeap, I know, I apply them everytime.